# How do i convert excel date type to anylogic dates?

Tags: date, anylogic

I'm trying to upload a database in anylogic that has dates. After the table is imported the dates are converted to dooble. this probably has to do with java but I'm not sure if there is an easier way to fix this.

Comment: Have you exported something with dates to see how it looks going the other direction?

Comment: If you set the xls date format correctly, it does work. You probably have some weird format going on, try several of Excel's settings